# Не используются переменные из __init__ в классе

Tags: python

При вызове класса Morse() появляется такая ошибка, хотя все переменные написаны правильно:

```
AttributeError: 'MyWidget' object has no attribute 'o'
```

Код:

```
class Morse(MyWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.o = []
        self.rus_to_morse = {'а': '.-',
                    'б': '-...',
                    'в': '.--',
                    'г': '--.',
                    'д': '-..',
                    'е': '.',
                    'ж': '...-',
                    'з': '--..',
                    'и': '..',
                    'й': '.---',
                    'к': '-.-',
                    'л': '.-..',
                    'м': '--',
                    'н': '-.',
                    'о': '---',
                    'п': '.--.',
                    'р': '.-.',
                    'с': '...',
                    'т': '-',
                    'у': '..-',
                    'ф': '..-.',
                    'х': '....',
                    'ц': '-.-.',
                    'ч': '---.',
                    'ш': '----',
                    'щ': '--.-',
                    'ъ': '.--.-.',
                    'ы': '-.--',
                    'ь': '-..-',
                    'э': '..-..',
                    'ю': '..--',
                    'я': '.-.-'}

    def convert(self, wordd):
        for i in wordd.split():
            self.o.append("".join(self.rus_to_morse[simv] for simv in i.lower()))
        self.output.setText(" ".join(self.o))

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_form):
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         self.setupUi(self)
         self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.run)
     def run(self):
         if self.encrypt.isChecked():
             if self.comboBox.activated[str]:
                 Morse.convert(self, self.input.toPlainText())
```

Comment: а родителя покажите для начала

Comment: Класс почти не зависит от родителя, может работать автономно, и даже если не связывать их, ошибка сохраняется

Comment: вот в этом "почти" возможно и дело, у меня ваш код с такой заменой (потому что родителя нет) - `print(" ".join(self.o))` работаешь без ошибок

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @Zhihar, вот родительский класс, но он зависит от python файла с дизайном, но он не помещается в комментарии `class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.run)

    def run(self):
        if self.encrypt.isChecked():
            if self.comboBox.activated[str]:
                Morse.convert(self, self.input.toPlainText())`

Comment: а `self.output` у вас у кого?

Comment: @Zhihar, это название QTextBrowser'а в файле с дизайном

Answer (score 2):

`Morse.convert` вызван из конструктора родительского класса `MyWidget`. То есть, он вызван до вызова конструктора `Morse` (конструкторы вызываются от предков к потомкам). А в этот момент поля `self.o` не существует.

Кроме того он вызывается для чужого экземпляра `self`. У `MyWidget` могут быть и другие потомки, кроме `Morse`.

Дизайн, где предки зависят от потомков обречен на подобные ошибки.